# Angular 4: setValue formBuilder empty array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-formbuilder

I have such reactive form:

```
constructor(...){
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)])],
    memes: this.formBuilder.array([
      this.initMemes('TrollFace')
    ])
  });
}

initMemes (name?) {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    id: [''], name: [name]
  });
}
```

later i can add some more `memes`:

```
addMemes () {
  const control = <FormArray>this.form.controls['memes'];
  control.push(this.initMemes('anyName'));
}
```

and then if i get form values i get:

`this.form.controls['memes'].value` - here i have array

But there is a case, when i need this `this.form.controls['memes'].value` to set to an empty array, how is it possible to do?

If i set it this way:

`this.form.controls['memes'].setValue([])`

I got error: `Must supply a value for form control at index: 0.`

what i do wrong?

Comment: For anyone who reads this: I struggled with this error after following a tutorial about FormArray. The solution is simple, just init the FormArray with a pair of empty square brackets []:  this.formBuilder.array([ ]). I don't know what the function call in there is supposed to do, I just know it gives that error.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**EDIT:**

As of newer versions, Angular now supports clearing a `FormArray` with `clear()`:

```
(<FormArray>this.form.get('memes')).clear();
```

---

**ORIGINAL:**

Tried a few things:`reset()`,`setControl()`, but the following was the only solution I found to work that actually resets the whole array to `[]`, other options worked, but they left the formgroups in place, just emptied the values.

So how I got it to work, was to iterate the form array and delete each form group with that particular index in the loop:

```
const control = <FormArray>this.form.controls['memes'];

for(let i = control.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  control.removeAt(i)
}
```

If there is a better way, I'm open for suggestions! :)

Comment: i think it should be control.controls.removeAt(i). Because the console.log(control) has a array with name controls otherwise you get the error "Cannot read property 'enabled' of null".

Comment: Thanks. This was the only solution that worked in this whole page.

Comment: Instead of the `for-loop`, you can just do `control.clear()`.

Answer (score 10):

Try `this.myForm.controls['myFormArray'] = this.formBuilder.array([]);` with formBuilder service instantiated in your constructor.

Comment: And we still do it like this in Angular 7

Comment: Doing this leaves the parent form invalid if the formArray had an invalid control before clearing it like this. The best way for Ng<8 is to use removeAt in a loop. For Angular 8+, use FormArray.clear() method

Answer (score 5):

**FORM**

```
this.form = this._formB.group({
    blocks: this._formB.array([])
});
```

**1st method**

```
let fArray = <FormArray>this.form.controls['blocks'];
while (fArray.length !== 0) {
  fArray.removeAt(0)
}
```

**2nd method**

```
this.form.setControl('blocks', this._formB.array([]));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer, this helps to OP as well as to other people that might end up here while searching for similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue, where I would get said error after updating my form, and after a bunch of investigation and failed experimentation I found that `this.myForm.updateValueAndValidity` finally did the trick.